# ASP.NET MVC using nHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I looking for some information on how to build an ASP.NET MVC application using nHibernate and n-tier layers.

Can I have example please.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [sample application](http://github.com/darind/samplemvc) you might take a look at. And an [accompanying blog post](http://www.bratched.com/en/component/content/article/62-how-we-do-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying Dariv, I can`t access your blog

Comment: @Darrin Dimitrov is the package missing SQLLite and/or is it a requirement? am getting this error when booting: `Error creating context 'spring.root': Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed. Inner: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver`

Answer (score 2):

[S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) is good for getting going with ASP.NET MVC and NHibernate.